# How to get the string value of the resultset

Tags: java, jdbc

I am wondering if there is a simple way that I could know the type of the resultset I get from some API not owned by me?

when I logged the type, it printed as 1003. Is there a way I could get the string correponding to 1003?

```
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
System.out.println(rs.getType());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing the result set type, which is probably not what you want. Please check the API documentation of `ResultSet`. Specifically for [`ResultSet.getType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getType()), the returned value of 1003 is the value of constant [`ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) (see [this documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY) for the values).

Given you don't explain what you want to achieve, I'm not sure what you need to do instead. If you really want to print the result set type, then you can do something like:

```
private String getResultSetTypeName(int resultSetType) {
    switch (resultSetType) {
    case ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY:
        return "TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY";
    case ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE:
        return "TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE";
    case ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE:
        return "TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE";
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid result set type value: " + resultSetType);
    }
}
```

And then use this method to convert the type code to a string.